# Глитчи запекания света в Unity 5.6

Tags: unity3d

При запекании света на сцене возникают глитчи и артефакты, как на фото. Что делать с этим? После нескольких повторов запекания правая стенка стала черной.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Попробуй Generate Lightmaps UVs https://answers.unity.com/questions/1735993/meshes-turn-black-after-baking-lightmap.html И вроде они должны быть "static" отмечены

Comment: @ValeraKvip спасибо, помогло